# Git to keep snapshots of a full Windows environment?

Tags: backup, git, restore

Is it possible/convenient to use Git to keep snapshots of a full computer running Windows?

I wonder if it could use simple Git branching to jump from one state to another and have different configurations and intalled programs, as well as testing new software without fearing malware infections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct tool for that sort of application would be a backup program. It sounds like you want to create an image of the computer, and programs like [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com), [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/), and [Norton Ghost](http://www.ghost.com/) are meant to do that.

You can also use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) to do testing. Sandboxie lets you run programs in isolated sandboxes, so if one of them goes haywire you can delete the sandbox and start over.

Not only would a full Windows system be much more information than Git was designed to keep track of, but there is other information that Git explicitly does *not* track such as NTFS permissions that would be lost when you "restore".

To be fair, [one person did set up a testing environment managed with Git](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200901#21), but he was using Windows 98 emulated under a legacy version of Win4lin. I'm guessing this environment isn't what you're looking to do, so I would avoid even considering it.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you'll never get full file system access while Windows is running, I'd have a hard time coming up with a **convenient** solution.